# PHP MySql get data from a table and left join to the same table

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have this table names MyLevels.

```
 id  | level | ParentLevelId
 ---------------------
 1   | basic | 1
 2   | silver| 1
 3   | gold  | 2
 4   | stone | 3
 5   | wood  | 2
```

on this table every level has a parent level. For example the `"gold"` level parent id is 2. It's mean the parent level is `"silver"`.
So I need a query to get the below in a html table:
Parent level comes from `ParentLevelId`.

```
level  | parent level | distance From Basic
-------------------------------------------
basic  | basic        | 0
silver | basic        | 1
gold   | silver       | 2
```

The distance from `basic` reference to the number that each level is far from `basic` level.
 
For example the `wood` level id is 5 and `5 - 1 = 4`. which means the it's 4 level far from `basic` level.
This is the only code I have:

```
$conn->prepare('SELECT id, level, ParentLevelId FROM MyLevels');
```

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this.

```
select c.level as level, p.level as parent_level, c.id-p.id as distance_from_parent
from MyLevels AS p
JOIN MyLevels AS c on p.id = c.ParentLevelId
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man. This worked perfectly. Where I can find a documentation for queries like this.

Comment: There is no proper documentation of this. But you need to learn about joins.

Comment: Where I can add count to get a result for each level to show how many sub level does have?

Answer (score 1):

can you try this ?

```
   SELECT a.level, b.level ParentLeve , IFNULL(b.id,0) FROM 
MyLevels a left join MyLevels b on a.id=b.ParentLevelId
```

Comment: Got error. It's not working.    Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'You have an error in your SQL syntax

Comment: I have updated ans can you check now. if error please write error

Comment: It's working now but not returning all columns. like ID and ParentLevelId as a name.

Comment: oh I have made a little mistake I need to take b. id . now check it you can give order by as you need :)

Answer (score 1):

Just another version to add to the fun.

I thought the op was wanting to get the Distance from basic, which in this case is id = 1.

Anyway, another way to write this is...

```
SELECT 
      b.level AS level, 
      a.level AS parent_level,
      b.id-1 AS distance_from_basic 
      FROM MyLevels a
        JOIN MyLevels b ON a.id = b.ParentLevelId
            ORDER BY b.id
```

This was tested against the desired results provided by the OP.

The results:

```
Level   Parent Level    Distance From Basic
basic   basic                  0
silver  basic                  1
gold    silver                 2
stone   gold                   3
wood    silver                 4
```